# Is it possible to encapsulate request parameters in request object?

Tags: http, request, guzzle, guzzle6

Is it possible to encapsulate request parameters in `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` object?

I would like to pass around a completely configured request object with request parameters instead of passing them to `Client::send()` method along with the request.

```
$request = new Reques('POST', $url);
$client->send($request, ['form_params' => $parameters]);
```

I'd like to store the `form_params` in the request object. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request` class constructor doesn't receive an argument as a request sending parameters. You may only pass request `headers`:

```
public function __construct(
    $method,
    $uri,
    array $headers = [],
    $body = null,
    $version = '1.1'
)
```

It doesn't provide any other methods to get and attach your POST parameters to the `Request` object either. So the answer is no, you can't store the `form_params` in the request object.

Comment: Isn't it a design flaw? As far as I can see `form_params` and many other request options are properties of request and should be encapsulated in it.

Comment: Somehow you are right, but as per you are able to set headers on instantiating a `Request`,  it means Guzzle sees HTTP headers like a piece of *static information* that can be repeated for multiple requests. So with one instance of `Request`, you could send multiple requests without the hassle of passing the same headers again and again. In return, it sees POST fields as *dynamic information* which should be merged to the request while it is going to be sent. So it needs to do it on each separate `Client`'s `send()` method call. Well, I see it legit. @Kolyunya